# Reset Azure PostgreSQL Server User Password through CLI

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-postgresql

How to change/reset the password for the User in Azure Postgresql Server through CLI.
I know there's a way how to reset password through Portal but am looking for resetting through Azure CLI .

I tried `ALTER USER {user} WITH PASSWORD '{password}';` but it needs superuser access. As far as I know, azure_superuser access is not granted so is there any way how to reset through CLI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a single Postgresql server, you can change the administrator role's password with the following CLI command:

```
az postgres server update --resource-group myresourcegroup --name mydemoserver --admin-password <new-password>
```

On a flexible Postgresql server, You can change the administrator role's password with this CLI command

```
az postgres flexible-server update --resource-group myresourcegroup --name mydemoserver --admin-password <new-password>
```

Choose a password that has a minimum of 8 characters and a maximum of 128 characters. The password must contain characters from three of the following categories:

- English uppercase letters
- English lowercase letters
- Numbers
- Non-alphanumeric characters

Comment: Can this be done via Azure Portal, do you know?

Comment: @Mitya. Sure you can. Please read here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/how-to-create-manage-server-portal#update-admin-password